# Pandas right to left pulling out partial string after second . else first . if 2 dont exist

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on pulling out anything after the second period going from right to left.  Some dont have two periods so it would be just the last part.  Others have multiple periods.  Is there a clever regex way to accomplish this?

```
df
    file_name
0   image001.png 
1   image002.jpg
2   image003.jpg
3   1234_001.pdf
4   machine datasheet.pdf
5   asdf_101010101.xlsx
6   not_malicious.docx.pdf
7   example.txt.scf
8   place 1010 - wiki edits.pdf
9   I LOVE YOU.TXT.vbs
10  test.test.read_this.pdf
```

Desired output:

```
df
    file_name
0   png 
1   jpg
2   jpg
3   pdf
4   pdf
5   xlsx
6   docx.pdf
7   txt.scf
8   pdf
9   TXT.vbs
10  read_this.pdf
```

Comment: Are you just looking for a regex solution?

Comment: It doesnt have to be @harvpan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to split `file_name` with `.` and then return last two from the list if the list size exceed 2, otherwise return last element.

```
df['file_name'].str.split('.').apply(lambda x: '.'.join(x[-2:]) if len(x)>2 else x[-1])
```

Output:

```
0               png
1               jpg
2               jpg
3               pdf
4               pdf
5              xlsx
6          docx.pdf
7           txt.scf
8               pdf
9           TXT.vbs
10    read_this.pdf
```